# Как найти лемму слова, используя словарь OpenCorpora?

Tags: естественный-язык

Пытаюсь сделать лемматизатор на основе словаря OpenCorpora, но никак не пойму как выудить из него лемму конкретного слова. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: А где ваш код, относящийся к вопросу?

Comment: @CrazyElf Не очень понял о каком коде идёт речь. Я бы хотел получить алгоритм действий для нахождения леммы в данном словаре, не более

Comment: Тут читали http://opencorpora.org/?page=export ? Лемма тоже понятие хитрое на самом деле.